# Android and sounds

Tags: android, audio

How I can add mp3 sounds to android project and after that add them to list? I add to the assets but I don;t know how I can add them to List
Thanks

Comment: What do you actually mean by list? A ListView? Do you want to show the files in a listview or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put them in a subfolder named 'raw' in your assets folder. Then you can refer to them as resources like you would an image or a string

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
 int[] resourceID=new int[fields.length];
  String[] names=new String[fields.length];
for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
    names[count]= fields[count].getName();<--- this is the list of names
     resourceID[count]=fields[count].getInt(fields[count]);<---- refer to those files using their ids in this array...(for example ..to play the audio.. u cannot get the file from name.. use this ids)
}
```

now pass the array to the adapter of your listview like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.text,R.id.textView1, Arrays.asList(names););
```